# Djagno: how to pass an email as a key in a dict to a template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to pass an email as a dictionary key to a django template.

This is possible

views.py

```
bad_dict = {'b@b.com': 1, 'c@c.com' :2 }
new_dict = { 'one' : 10, 'two' : 20 }
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'a.html',
                   {'bad_dict': bad_dict,
                   'new_dict':new_dict})
```

html

```
aa{{ bad_dict.b@b.com }}bb
aa{{ new_dict.one }}bb
```

If you use`aa{{ new_dict.one }}bb` it works perfectly and you get aa10bb. 
However, if you use `aa{{ bad_dict.b@b.com }}bb` it gives you this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '@b.com' from 'bad_dict.b@b.com'
```

Is there anyway to get around this? I supposed I could strip '@' and '.', but that seems to coarse. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the @? No idea if that would work, just curious...

Comment: I tried "{% autoescape on %}", but it didn't work. The problem with escaping is that i'm not going to be calling these one by one, but am going to be comparing each value to a user.email field that I'm looping through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write [cutom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) for this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_by_email(value, arg):
    return value.get(arg)
```

In template it will looks like this:

```
{{ bad_dict|get_by_email:"b@b.com" }}
```